# Convert id indicator columns to one ID column

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I would like to convert multiple binary id indicator columns to one id column.

My input:

```
       var1   var2  id1   id2  id3
obs1    .       .    0     1    0
obs2    .       .    1     0    0
obs3    .       .    0     0    1
```

My desired output:

```
       var1   var2  id1   id2  id3  id
obs1    .       .    0     1    0    2
obs2    .       .    1     0    0    1
obs3    .       .    0     0    1    3
```

Comment: Like this? `id <- ifelse(id1 == 1, 1, ifelse(id2 == 1, 2, 3))` Or how to you go from the id-columns to id?

Answer (score 2):

```
> df$id <- which(df[,-c(1,2)]==1, arr.ind = TRUE)[, 1]
> df
     var1 var2 id1 id2 id3 id
obs1    .    .   0   1   0  2
obs2    .    .   1   0   0  1
obs3    .    .   0   0   1  3
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `max.col`

```
df1$id <- max.col(df1[grep("id", names(df1))])
df1
#     var1 var2 id1 id2 id3 id
#obs1    .    .   0   1   0  2
#obs2    .    .   1   0   0  1
#obs3    .    .   0   0   1  3
```